# Loader onLoadFinished: Posting command vs direct execution

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loader

When you need to update UI in `loader#onLoadFinished`, especially committing fragment transactions, I saw numerous examples when people post a runnable rather than executing directly, for instance :

*Update* : loader's callbacks run on UI thread.

1.

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Void> loader, Void result) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            hideDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

vs

2.

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Void> loader, Void result) {
    hideDialog();
}
```

where `hideDialog` does some fragment transactions :

```
private void hideDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) { 
        ft.remove(prev).commit();
    }
}
```

What is the reason to prefer approach 1 vs 2 ?

I bet it has to do with avoiding fragment transactions (in `hideDilaog`) happen after current fragment `onSaveInstanceState`, but I don't see how approach 1 help in this case.

Are they essentially equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

If you `initLoader()` from your UI thread, then `onLoadFinished()` will be running on the UI thread as well, so you can just do the `hideDialog()` right away. If you init your loader from a background thread though, than the `onLoadFinished()` will be running on this background thread, thus you'll need a handler.

So, if you're writing your own custom Loaders that you're not sure how will be started (for example if they are part of some library), then it's a good idea to have something like this in `onLoadFinished()`

```
Runnable refreshUI = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // refresh UI elements here
    }
};

if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
    // you're directly on the UI thread, so just run the runnable
    refreshUI.run();
} else {
    // on a background thread, use a handler
    handler.post(refreshUI);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I haven't mention that everything runs on UI thread. I updated the question.

Comment: In that case I don't see a reason for going for option 1. Will be interested to see other comments and thoughts :)